# Build Nearest Neighbor Classification Boundary

Tags: scikit-learn, nearest-neighbor

Is there any method to build the classification boundary with all the iris feature instead of only using 2 features? Thank you.

Here is the code of KNN with classification boundary with all the 2 iris feature:
http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/neighbors/plot_classification.html#example-neighbors-plot-classification-py
Can I include all the features?

Comment: Please provide some example code or explain in more details.

Comment: I have added more details. Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
X = iris.data[:, :2]  # we only take the first two features. We could
                      # avoid this ugly slicing by using a two-dim dataset
```

with `X = iris.data`

Also put in comment all code that responsible for plotting 2 dimensional graph. If you want to draw it any way, use some kind of dimension reduction technique like PCA.

Comment: And what was the result?

Comment: it gives a error. ValueError: query data dimension must match training data dimension